# HTML 5 Substitute to javascript validation

Tags: html

I would like to know if HTML5 validation could already by used as a substitute to javascript validation.

HTML validation is so much easier and I want to implement it in my website but I am not sure of it is safe enough.

Comment: Only if you don't expect to support IE8 or IE9, and probably some edge cases in other browsers. Take a look at http://html5test.com/ for support of HTML 5 features in browsers, and then look for the browser's marketshare.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 validation is a feature [that is fully implemented in several browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs.html#t12), but is not fully implemented in many older browser versions, **notably IE <10, Safari (all versions), as well as older versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Opera**.

For those browsers that do not support it, however, you should look into using [a Javascript polyfill such as Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) to ensure that users with other browsers will have their inputs validated as well. (There may be other polyfills available, but Modernizr is the most popular and widespread option currently available)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this resource for HTML5 validations (see the `required` attribute). It goes on to explain browser compatibility:

http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html